# autoComplete.js Unterminated group error when typing an opening parenthesis

Tags: autocomplete

I am trying to implement [autoComplete.js](https://github.com/TarekRaafat/autoComplete.js) on this site: http://bydaylight.com/testing/patent-defenses/

Some of the terms in our data have parenthesis like this:

112(1/a)

When I start typing in that exact string, I get an error after typing the opening parenthesis

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /112(/: Unterminated group
```

[autocomplete.js error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aabW6.png)

The data itself is just a simple array. Looks like this:

```
["100", "101", "112", "119", "120", "135", "273", "287", "295", "365", "102(e) ", "112(1/a)", "112(2/b)", "112(4/d)", "112(6/f) ", "271(a)", "271(b)", "271(c) ", "271(e)  ", "271(f) ", "271(g)", "abatement", "ACQUIESCENCE", "admitted prior art", "Alice"]
```

Is there any special formatting I need to consider? Just looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because of `autoComplete.js` matching method in `strict` mode is regex which conflicts with the brackets because it's considered as an invalid character and should be escaped inside regex pattern.

So you've two options for now to solve your issue:

1. Use `loose` mode instead of `strict`
2. Escape invalid characters before processing through `query`